# Using other pic microcontrollers instead of the PIC12C508 (arcade monitor protection circuit

Tags: microcontroller, pic, vga, monitor

I want to use another microcontroller because the **PIC12C508** isn't available in my country (philippines) I want to use the **PIC16f628a** or **PIC12F510** but I don't know what pins to use and if they're compatible.

**edit:** I don't have coding knowledge but i know how to program them. The source code is in the site below.

---

More info on the circuit

The **monitor protection circuit** protects (cuts off the sync if it's higher than 15Khz) the arcade monitor (which is CGA) from sync frequency being higher than **15Khz** when the pc boots. The pc uses **VGA** with a breakout wire and will run on **soft 15Khz**.

It also **amplifies** the VGA signal that is 1 volt peak to peak to 5 volts.

---

The artcicle is here http://members.optusnet.com.au/eviltim/vga2arc/vga2arc.htm.

here is the circuit: [intelligent direct coupled video amplifier](http://members.optusnet.com.au/eviltim/vga2arc/dcvidi.png)

---

The hex file

```
:10000000A80C02000C0C0600660061002107060A1D
:100010006C006100AC0261070A0A740C8C000307D3
:0E002000140A020C2600050A210C2600050A0F
:021FFE00EA0FE8
:00000001FF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Do you have the source code for this project? The PIC12C508 is very basic compared to the other two microcontrollers you mentioned, and this program should be easy to duplicate on the newer chip if we could see the code.</s>

It's very unlikely that the hex file you provided will work on the chips you have access to. In theory you could disassemble that hex into assembly but I have no experience in that process.

Edit: Found [this](http://members.optusnet.com.au/eviltim/vgastop.asm) on the first page linked. This is a fairly simple program. It's not well documented but it should work with little modification.

Your question about pins can be answered by finding the datasheets for the PICs in question. The easiest way to do that is to Google the full name of the PIC and choose a link that starts with "www.microchip.com". [Here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41268D.pdf) is the datasheet for the PIC12F510. All Microchip PIC datasheets follow a similar format. There is usually a cover page, then a page with legal information, then a device overview page(PDF page 3). The next page of this datasheet has the pinout diagrams for the different packages. You are probably using the 8 pin PDIP package.

Comparing the datasheets tells us that the PIC12C509 and the PIC12F510 are pin-compatible.

So yes, you can use the 12F510 in this project. Moving forward, what do you know about programming a PIC? Do you already have the tools to program a PIC?

Comment: thanks for the answer! I don't have any programming knowledge about pics but i know how to plug the chip in and copy paste the code and push the upload button. Heres my programmer <http://www.e-gizmo.com/KIT/ePIC-KIT2.htm>

Comment: Excellent. PICs are difficult to get started with, so if you can already program them that means the hard part is done. My assembly is a little rusty, but if you don't mind waiting a day or two I can try to modify that code and post the hex on here.

Comment: Its ok i can wait, i dont have the monitor yet. But thanks for that